# Why when using object pooling and trying to put the objects in random positions on terrain it's not random?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this pooling script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ObjectPool
{
    private GameObject prefab;

    private List<GameObject> pool;

    public ObjectPool(GameObject prefab, int initialSize)
    {
        this.prefab = prefab;

        this.pool = new List<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++)
        {
            AllocateInstance();
        }
    }

    public GameObject GetInstance()
    {
        if (pool.Count == 0)
        {
            AllocateInstance();
        }

        int lastIndex = pool.Count - 1;
        GameObject instance = pool[lastIndex];
        pool.RemoveAt(lastIndex);

        instance.SetActive(true);
        return instance;
    }

    public void ReturnInstance(GameObject instance)
    {
        instance.SetActive(false);
        pool.Add(instance);
    }

    protected virtual GameObject AllocateInstance()
    {
        GameObject instance = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);
        instance.SetActive(false);
        pool.Add(instance);

        return instance;
    }
}
```

And i'm using it with this script to instantiate objects.
It should put the objects in random positions around the terrain area.
But instead all the objects are in the same position at x = 0 , y = 20 , z = 0
Not random at all.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class InstantiateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Spaceship;
    public int spaceshipsStartingHeight = 20;
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject[] spaceships;

    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _spaceshipCount;
    private float _spaceshipSize;
    private List<int> randomNumbers = new List<int>();
    private ObjectPool bulletPool;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int SpaceShipCount;
    public float SpaceShipSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rndNumbers();
        Clone();
        spaceships = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpaceShip");
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        SpaceShipCount = Mathf.Max(0, SpaceShipCount);
        SpaceShipSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, SpaceShipSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        SpaceShipCount = 100;
        SpaceShipSize = 20.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void Clone()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && SpaceShipCount == _spaceshipCount && Mathf.Approximately(SpaceShipSize, _spaceshipSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var ShipsToDestroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpaceShip");
        foreach (var t in ShipsToDestroy)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        bulletPool = new ObjectPool(Spaceship, SpaceShipCount);

        for (var i = 0; i < SpaceShipCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject o = bulletPool.GetInstance();
            o.tag = "SpaceShip";
            o.transform.SetParent(base.gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SpaceShipSize, SpaceShipSize, SpaceShipSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            //o.transform.Rotate(0.0f,randomNumbers[i],0.0f);
            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y + spaceshipsStartingHeight, z);
        }

        _extents = Extents;
        _spaceshipCount = SpaceShipCount;
        _spaceshipSize = SpaceShipSize;
    }

    public void rndNumbers()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: where and how are you setting the position?

Comment: @KevinGosse inside the Clone method in this part i get the position // get random position then in the bottom near the bottom set the position: o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y + spaceshipsStartingHeight, z);

Comment: @KevinGosse oops forgot to add the second script where i position the objects. Added it now.

Comment: Your _Extents_ is always `(0, 0, 0)`, therefore your _x, y_ and _z_ are never going to be random.

Comment: @Hristo since i'm using now the pooling i removed the whole destroy part from the Update, The whole // cleanup part. Now it's creating the objects random. Now i wonder that's what i wanted to do is how to make in the Update() that when i change the SpaceShipCount value in the Inspector it will release the objects using the pooling and will create new objects according to the new value i entered in the inspector ?

Comment: @TheLostLostit I believe this should be another post, please take your time to answer your own question so other people can find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to remove the whole // cleanUp part inside the Clone(). Now it's creating random objects using the pooling.